# loading large JSON to use in a SPA

Tags: javascript, html, json, single-page-application

I need to provide a large JSON (500MB+) locally to use in a HTML Single-Page-Application. The JSON consists of Data-Sets to use in numerous Data-Tables. The final SPA should run whitout using a localhost Server, so it can run from disk and platform independent (Desktop-Browser, Mobile-Browser, etc.). To my understanding, I need to convert it to an Object in a JS-File to even load it.

I would like to know, if this is even feasible or how I would go about it.

- should the data be converted in a more useable format?
- is there a way to use Databases?
- splitting the Data-Sets is possible, but how would I load the separated files w/o localhost

Searching Stack and the Web for several days didn't result in any insight. Help and Hints much appreciated!

Comment: 500MB is a lot... The typical approach when handling big datasets is to load chunks in pages in the SPA using AJAX and a webserver. Is this what you want?

Comment: _The final SPA should run without using a localhost Server, so it can run from disk_ what do you mean by this?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen that's what I would like to use. However it's requested, that the SPA is capable of loading from disk (e.g. USB-Stick or internal Storage) without restrictions on OS (e.g. Browser on Desktop: Windows, Mac and Browsers on mobile Devices: Android, iOS)
for me this seems impossible, but as I'm fairly new to Web-Dev I might miss something

Comment: Best bet would be to put in an XML or CSV file and using some form of parser like [papaparse](http://papaparse.com/#stream) to read it. Papaparse can do line-by-line operations, thus make handling that size of data possible.